# can't receive MQTT message using Paho under spring integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, activemq-classic, paho

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class WyymqttApplication {

@Value("${spring.mqtt.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${spring.mqtt.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${spring.mqtt.url}")
private String hostUrl;

@Value("${spring.mqtt.client.id}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${spring.mqtt.default.topic}")
private String defaultTopic;

private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(WyymqttApplication.class);

public static void main(final String... args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WyymqttApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public MqttConnectOptions getMqttConnectOptions() {
    MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
    mqttConnectOptions.setUserName(username);
    mqttConnectOptions.setPassword(password.toCharArray());
    mqttConnectOptions.setServerURIs(new String[]{hostUrl});
    mqttConnectOptions.setKeepAliveInterval(2);
    return mqttConnectOptions;
}

@Bean
public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
    DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
    factory.setConnectionOptions(getMqttConnectOptions());
    return factory;
}

//publisher

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mqttOutFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource.stdin(),
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
            .transform(p -> p + " sent to MQTT")
            .handle(mqttOutbound())
            .get();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttOutboundChannel")
public MessageHandler mqttOutbound() {
    MqttPahoMessageHandler messageHandler = new MqttPahoMessageHandler(clientId, mqttClientFactory());
    messageHandler.setAsync(true);
    messageHandler.setDefaultTopic(defaultTopic);
    return messageHandler;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel mqttOutboundChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "mqttOutboundChannel")
public interface MqttGateway {
    void sendToMqtt(String data, @Header(MqttHeaders.TOPIC) String topic);
}

// consumer

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(mqttInbound())
            .transform(p -> p + ", received from MQTT")
            .handle(logger())
            .get();
}


private LoggingHandler logger() {
    LoggingHandler loggingHandler = new LoggingHandler("INFO");
    loggingHandler.setLoggerName("siSample");
    return loggingHandler;
}

@Bean
public MessageProducerSupport mqttInbound() {
    MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("siSampleConsumer",
            mqttClientFactory(), defaultTopic);
    adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
    adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
    adapter.setQos(1);
    return adapter;
}
```

}

Here is my code.Above is my code, I use ActiveMQ as a broker. When I send a message on the command line, the message can be sent, but I can't receive it.

Messages like this:

2018-08-06 11:18:02.107  INFO 2508 --- [iSampleConsumer] siSample                                 : hello stackoverflow sent to MQTT, received from MQTT

Comment: There is nothing to say about your code. Although I'm not sure why you show us an `outbound` part since you send via command line. Also you don't show what symptoms you have so far: is there a connection from the application on the broker side? I believe there should be some logs on the matter when your application starts and connects to the brokers. Might be some errors because of wrong conversion and so on...

Comment: This looks like it's based on the MQTT sample app, which works fine (I just tested it again). I suggest you compare debug logs between your app and the unmodified sample.

Comment: From your log I see that you received message. According to your code ", received from MQTT" - that substring added in your consumer.
You publishing and listening same topic. I tested your sample and it works.